# How to have multiple colums in a variable/array

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query

```
select expiration_date, driver_id from all_requirements_driver_documents where expiration_date <= (now() + interval '1 month')::DATE and expiration_date > (now() - interval '7 day')::DATE
union
select expiration_date, driver_id from all_requirements_vehicle_documents where expiration_date <= (now() + interval '1 month')::DATE and expiration_date > (now() - interval '7 day')::DATE
```

I want to insert it into a variable in which I can loop and perform actions.

i.e `unsatified_documents driver_expiring_documents;`

where

```
create table if not exists driver_expiring_documents (
    driver_id text,
    expiration_date date
);
```

and then loop through it

```
if(unsatified_documents != '{}') then
     foreach expiring_doc in array unsatified_documents loop
     -- -- Get Driver ID --
        driver_id_arg := expiring_doc.driver_id;
         expiring_date := expiring_doc.expiration_date;

     end loop;
 end if;
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You *can* store it in an array variable, but if you want to loop through the results, that would be unnecessarily complicated and inefficient. You'd have to pack it into a data structure that potentially uses a lot of RAM, only to unpack it right away.

Simply do

```
DECLARE
   r record;
BEGIN
   FOR r IN
      select expiration_date, driver_id from ... WHERE ...
      union
      select expiration_date, driver_id from ... where ...
   LOOP
      /* do something with "r.expiration_date" and "r.driver_id" */
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom type, for example:

```
CREATE TYPE my_doc
AS
(
    driver_id text,
    expiration_date date
);
```

Then, if you want make an array of these values you can do:

```
SELECT array_agg((driver_id, expiration_date)::my_doc)
FROM driver_expiring_documents;
```

But you don't even need the array, which can be pretty big, you can just loop in a function with this simple query:

```
SELECT (driver_id, expiration_date)::my_doc
FROM driver_expiring_documents;
```

Or, you can skip the intermediate table and select with the union:

```
select (expiration_date, driver_id)::my_doc from all_requirements_driver_documents where expiration_date <= (now() + interval '1 month')::DATE and expiration_date > (now() - interval '7 day')::DATE
union
select (expiration_date, driver_id)::my_doc from all_requirements_vehicle_documents where expiration_date <= (now() + interval '1 month')::DATE and expiration_date > (now() - interval '7 day')::DATE
```

And just a consideration: if you can, use UNION ALL, it will be faster.